# Returning a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, asp-classic, return

I am trying to create a simple function that will return the correct string when called:

```
function getState(abbr){
   if (abbr=="WY")
   {
   return "Wyoming";
   }
}
```

and then the call is like this:

```
var stateName = getState("WY");
```

However all that is getting returned is: 0

Sorry if I am missing something obvious.

UPDATE - my orig prob was because of a "&" here's the real code I'm dealing with:

```
function getState(abbr){
    var url = "states.asp"
    var state = ""; 
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        var i = 0;
        $.each($('state',data),function(index, el) {            
            if (abbr == ($(this).attr("abbr"))){
                //alert($(this).attr("abbr"));
                state = $(this).text();
            }//if (abbr == $(this).attr("abbr")){
        });//$.each($('state',data),function(index, el) {
    }).success(function() { 
        alert("x" + state);
        return state;
    }); //.success(function() { 
    //$.get(url, function(data) {
    alert("y" + state); 
    return state;
}
```

I am getting "undefined" as a result to my call:

```
alert(getState("WY"));
```

Alert("x" + state) works.

UPDATE #2 ---
here is all that states.asp generates (for now)... later it will return companies, etc:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<STATELIST>
<STATE abbr="AL">Alabama</STATE>
<STATE abbr="AK">Alaska</STATE>
<STATE abbr="AZ">Arizona</STATE>
<STATE abbr="AR">Arkansas</STATE>
<STATE abbr="CA">California</STATE>
<STATE abbr="CO">Colorado</STATE>
<STATE abbr="CT">Connecticut</STATE>
<STATE abbr="DE">Delaware</STATE>
<STATE abbr="FL">Florida</STATE>
<STATE abbr="GA">Georgia</STATE>
<STATE abbr="HI">Hawaii</STATE>
<STATE abbr="ID">Idaho</STATE>
<STATE abbr="IL">Illinois</STATE>
<STATE abbr="IN">Indiana</STATE>
<STATE abbr="IA">Iowa</STATE>
<STATE abbr="KS">Kansas</STATE>
<STATE abbr="KY">Kentucky</STATE>
<STATE abbr="LA">Louisiana</STATE>
<STATE abbr="ME">Maine</STATE>
<STATE abbr="MD">Maryland</STATE>
<STATE abbr="MA">Massachusetts</STATE>
<STATE abbr="MI">Michigan</STATE>
<STATE abbr="MN">Minnesota</STATE>
<STATE abbr="MS">Mississippi</STATE>
<STATE abbr="MO">Missouri</STATE>
<STATE abbr="MT">Montana</STATE>
<STATE abbr="NE">Nebraska</STATE>
<STATE abbr="NV">Nevada</STATE>
<STATE abbr="NH">New Hampshire</STATE>
<STATE abbr="NJ">New Jersey</STATE>
<STATE abbr="NM">New Mexico</STATE>
<STATE abbr="NY">New York</STATE>
<STATE abbr="NC">North Carolina</STATE>
<STATE abbr="ND">North Dakota</STATE>
<STATE abbr="OH">Ohio</STATE>
<STATE abbr="OK">Oklahoma</STATE>
<STATE abbr="OR">Oregon</STATE>
<STATE abbr="PA">Pennsylvania</STATE>
<STATE abbr="RI">Rhode Island</STATE>
<STATE abbr="SC">South Carolina</STATE>
<STATE abbr="SD">South Dakota</STATE>
<STATE abbr="TN">Tennessee</STATE>
<STATE abbr="TX">Texas</STATE>
<STATE abbr="UT">Utah</STATE>
<STATE abbr="VT">Vermont</STATE>
<STATE abbr="VA">Virginia</STATE>
<STATE abbr="WA">Washington</STATE>
<STATE abbr="WV">West Virginia</STATE>
<STATE abbr="WI">Wisconsin</STATE>
<STATE abbr="WY">Wyoming</STATE>
</STATELIST>
```

Comment: How are you using `stateName` to get the output?

Comment: Are you sure there's no typos in your script, that should work as written here.

Comment: This is pure javascript (not jQuery).  [This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwhitted/EsV8c/) shows that your exact code works as you would expect.  You'll need to show us your actual function and code calling it for any additional help.

Comment: i just literally tried this in the console and it's working as it should.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Wf5gm/ the console reads your code fine.

Comment: Can you post the content that is returned by `states.asp` ?

Comment: User1919108, revealing your "real code" late in the day is a great way **not** to win friends. It's a critical part of the question and should have been stated at the outset!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Easiest approach is to make a hash - no function needed.

```
var states = {
    'AL': 'Alabama',
    'AK': 'Alaska',
    'AZ': 'Arizona',
    'AR': 'Arkansas',
    'CA': 'California',
    'CO': 'Colorado',
    'CT': 'Connecticut',
    ...
    'WY': 'Wyoming'
};

var stateName = states["WY"];
```

### EDIT

Now I better understand that `getState()` needs to retrieve State names from the server. This puts you into the world of asynchronous coding, which is quite different from normal, synchronous coding.

The most important thing to realise is that `getState()` can't simply return a state name for a given state abbreviation. Why? Because the ajax call to the server is *asynchronous* - in other words `getState()` won't wait for the server's response before returning.

There are essentially two approaches to handling asynchronicity :

- pass callback function(s) to `getState()` to tell it what to do when a response is received
- arrange for `getState()` to return a special type of object called a "promise" which can be handled where `getState()` is called, in such a way that it will respond when the server has responded.

The code below adopts the second approach.

```
var states = {};//cache of state names, with state abbreviations as keys
function getState(abbr) {
    var dfrd = $.Deferred();//A deferred object, whose promise will be returned.
    if(!states[abbr]) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "states.asp",
            dataType: 'XML',
            success: function(data) {
                //Load up the cache
                $.each($('state', data), function(i, el) {
                    states[el.attr('abbr')] = $(el).text();
                });
                //Now resolve or reject the deferred object depending in whether states[abbr] has been cached
                if(states[abbr]) {
                    dfrd.resolve(abbr, states[abbr]);//Success! Let's resolve the deferred object (and its promise).
                }
                else {
                    dfrd.reject(abbr, 'States successfully downloaded but ' + abbr + ' was not included');
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                dfrd.reject(abbr, 'Download of states failed');
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        //The state name is already cached
        //The deferred object (and its promise) can be resolved without needing to make another ajax call.
        dfrd.resolve(abbr, states[abbr]);
    }
    return dfrd.promise();
}
```

*untested*

Now all you need to know is how to call `getState()`.

```
getState("WY").done(function(abbr, state) {
    alert(abbr + ': ' + state);
    //other stuff here
}).fail(function(abbr, message) {
    alert(abbr + ': ' + message);
    //other stuff here
});
```

As you can see, the value that you wanted `getState()` to return now appears as the second argument of a `.done()` function. For good measure, the abbreviation ("WY") appears as the first argument.

If you want to handle error conditions (always a good idea), then do so in a `.fail()` callback.

See comments in code for more clues as to how everything works.

Comment: Clever.  And it would prevent the need of processing through all the non-matches by getting the exact key's value.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful to know. However, I am going to need to return more than just the abbr & state name... the abbr is just so I know which state I am looking for. I'm just not sure why I am not getting a result from the return.

Comment: You need to understand that ajax is asynchronous. I have edited above to provide an explanation and some code. Don't worry if you don't get it first time through - it's quite advanced stuff, which will probably blow you mind at least slightly. Deferreds/promises took me a while to learn.

Answer (score 6):

There is absolutely nothing broken in your code. See this [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kw6aS/).

```
function getState(abbr){
   if (abbr=="WY")
   {
   return "Wyoming";
   }
}
var stateName = getState("WY");
alert(stateName);
​
```

Comment: Sorry... it was a typo in my code after all (i was using an "&" instead of a "+" to concatenate the string). I've been using JQuery regularly for a few weeks now and have yet to figure out how to get alerted of errors such as this... any suggestions?

Comment: Hit F12 to launch your browser dev tools. Use the console tab to locate JS errors. The dev tools are all pretty similar in all browsers. For FF you need to install FireBug, the other major browsers have dev tools build in.

Comment: "have yet to figure out how to get alerted of errors such as this"  ---     

Try a linter

Answer (score 3):

HTML:

```
<div id="msg">...</div>
```

JS:

```
function getState(abbr){
   if (abbr=="WY")
   {
   return "Wyoming";
   }
}
var stateName = getState("WY");
​document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML=stateName;
```

Answer (score 2):

That's going to be a lot of `if` statements to evaluate: the function would potentially have to go through all 50 `if` statements to get to Wyoming! I'd rewrite it with a `switch` statement, like that:

```
function getState(abbr){

   switch case(abbr) {

      case "WY":
         return "Wyoming";
      ...

   }
}
```

I think this should be faster. I would also add a `default` case, just in case the input is bad.

Answer (score 0):

This is just my solution. I'm still grabbing at straws trying to understand asynch behaviour, but here's what worked:

Instead of:

```
function searchServing(which,choice){
   var state = getState("WY");
   $("#searchResults").html("<tr><td>" + state + "</td></tr>");
   .get(function() {

   } //for reference call this getSearchServing
}
```

i had to reverse the call so:

```
function getState(abbr){
  .get(function(){
      $("#searchResults").html("<tr><td>" + state + "</td></tr>");
  })
  .success(function() { 
    searchServing('serving',abbr);
  })
}
```

still not sure why getSearchServing would run before getState and not sure why I couldn't return a value from getState ???

Comment: Tree, your question, including its major edit, is all about `getState()` - a function that translates a state abbreviation into the full state name. Your own answer above makes no sense whatsoever. It doesn't address the internal working of `getState()`, and in any case isn't valid javascript - it throws a syntax error. I can only venture to suggest that you have not yet found a solution.

Comment: @ Beetroot-Beetroot... When I put alerts in both functions the searchSearving(.get()) would run before getState(.get()). even though  getState(.get()) was called first... Basically I never figured out how to pass the info so I just printed the results from getState() instead. I acknowledge it's not the absolute solution. But it works well enough.